# space above header in fire fox on 2 pages of our website. Others ok

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox

[This page](http://thebc.co/website-design-graphic-design) and [this page](http://thebc.co/los-angeles-music-licensing-mastering-consulting) have a space over the header.  They just appeared after an update but I am missing where the problem could be.

Note: This only happens in FireFox.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd check is whether your markup's valid.  [According to the w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://thebc.co/website-design-graphic-design&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), you've got an unclosed `div` somewhere.  In my experience that's exactly the kind of thing that'll cause different presentation in different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `margin-top: 16px;` from `#header`.

Also reduce `padding-top: 5px;`   from  `#header .inner`,

Answer (score 0):

.column, .columns in this class float:left; and display:inline causing problem... please try to remove those two properties but it may effect in some other places.. do one thing in the header id place the float:none; so it will effect only for header.

```
#header {clear: both;  display: inline-block; float: none; margin-top: 16px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.column, .columns {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

In this class `float:left`inside is redundant, remove he is normal. and the two class to write it separately. like this:

```
.columns {      
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.column{
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the `columns` or entire `sixteen columns` class from `header`, it has no use there, only a small left `padding` for the logo, that's all what you'll miss. Now it's in conflict with `.columns` css styles.

Or you could rewrite the css for that class that would apply only for header.

After removing columns class in chrome and ff on mac:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just found the issue.  I had

```
#artists {margin-bottom: 40px}
#album-design {margin-bottom: 40px}
```

I changed it to:

```
#artists {padding-bottom: 40px}
#album-design {padding-bottom: 40px}
```

I know this is the issue because it was only happening on the portfolio and music page, the only two pages with that particular CSS.

Anyone out there care to check it?

Thanks for all of the answers.  Most let me know of other issues I will fix.

Thank you all.